# associate discrete r.v.s to continuous r.v.s

Tags: probability, random-variables

I've read this statement in a probability text book:

Let X be a non-negative r.v. with a continuous, strictly increasing CDF F, and let I be an indicator r.v. Then:

$$X = \int_0^\infty I(X \geq t) dt$$

Since I is an indicator r.v., it should be a discrete r.v., so the formula essentially correlates continuous r.v. to discrete r.v., but the book doesn't give any proof.

Could anybody prove this statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a case of rewriting carefully what that means: for every $t\geq 0$,
$$
I(X\geq t) = \begin{cases} 1& \text{ if } X\geq t\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and therefore
$$
\int_0^\infty I(X\geq t) dt = \int_0^X \underbrace{I(X\geq t)}_{=1} dt + \int_X^\infty \underbrace{I(X\geq t)}_{=0} dt = \int_0^X dt = X\,.
$$